# The topic area ".NET async/await/TPL" needs a canonical answer on cooperative cancellation

Tags: discussion, canonical

In the .NET space there has been a lot of interest in things like async, await and TPL in the recent years. A very common issue is that someone expects cancellation to be one of these:

1. immediate
2. pre-emptive (as opposed to cooperative)
3. as easy as the `Task.Run(..., cancellationToken)` API makes it seem
4. somehow built into `async/await`.

We need a canonical answer that explains...

1. ...that cancellation is cooperative by nature
2. ...how to achieve it when a cancellation token can be passed
3. ...how to cancel when the API you are calling is not cooperating (e.g. by isolating and ignoring the still running action)
4. ...common mistakes such as expecting `Task.Run(..., cancellationToken)` to always work
5. ...that `Thread.Abort` is not a solution although it appears to work.

Subjectively I think we have about 10 questions per week that require a rote answer to explain one of the points above. [Here's the latest one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835080/c-sharp-cancel-execution-of-a-task-with-multiple-tasks-in-it) There are a lot of them in total with very few unique issues among them:

[image]

I did not find a good canonical that can be used to **routinely close off cancellation questions**.

Putting this here in case someone is interested in spending maybe 1 hour to create a comprehensive nice canonical answer. The goal should be to come to a place where we routinely close off these questions just like we do with `NullReferenceException`. The canonical `NullReferenceException` works excellently for this purpose.

Comment: I nominate Stephen Cleary, should he choose to accept it :)

Comment: Also if you write a high quality canonical, there's a good chance that [Madara](http://stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha) will give you a nice bounty.

Comment: It definitely would need some work as it is super specific right now but I have [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36754085/how-to-get-handle-of-an-awaitable-task/36756606#36756606) that covers part of how cancellation tokens are used. If you think that question is a good candidate I can work on improving my answer.

Comment: Madara appears to be an awesome user. I did not know about his mission to promote excellent content.

Comment: @Phaeze I find that answer to be too specific. I have given my idea of question and answer in this meta post as an outline. It really needs to cover everything comprehensively so that we can **routinely close questions** without much work.

Comment: @usr yeah I agree,  if the question was a good fit I would put the time in to make the answer more comprehensive. I admittedly knew nothing about cancellation tokens before developing that answer.

Comment: @Phaeze if you choose to take this on, don't improve this answer. Work on a freshly written question and answer pair that is free of cruft. As the answer stands it covers very little of the material that I proposed anyway. That's why I'm surprised you mention that answer as a candidate.

Comment: @Phaeze if you want feedback on that answer, `by calling await on a Task or async method we are actually suspending that thread so it will block any successive code` is not accurate. `await` releases the thread (kind of), it does not suspend it. Not trying to put down your experience but maybe this task is one notch above your current skill?! I can't know for sure.

Comment: @usr, fair enough and I do agree that I would need to do some reading to be able to take on this task.

Comment: @David L: I look forward to - nay, I *await* - his contribution of such an answer.

Comment: That can be expanded to thread/process cancellation in general, and even further to suspending/resuming threads in general. That's only the proverbial tip of the ice berg. About a year ago [suspend resume](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=suspend+resume) was at 2330, now we have over 3100. That's depressing.

Comment: @JensG I think that's a great idea but for another canonical. Maybe you want to propose it on Meta.; I find that Stack Overflow is very weak on creating canonicals. It takes 1000 repeated questions until someone writes up the issue. Such a waste of time.

Comment: Is this something that would be best placed on the new Documentation site?

Comment: @volt Only if we can close questions as duplicates of something posted to the Documentation site.

Comment: If written, it would also be nice to make people aware that often tasks or async is misused in place of an event driven approach. re: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx (I would also like to see someone like Stephen Cleary write this)

Answer (score -5):

I like to redirect people to this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andrewarnottms/2014/03/19/recommended-patterns-for-cancellationtoken/

Comment: Redirecting people off-site isn't what we want to do, nor is it what this question is asking for.